# Obter referência de TAGs filha de um XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clientes>
    <cliente>
        <nome>Cliente1</nome>
        <contatos>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato1</nome>
            </contato>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato2</nome>
            </contato>
        </contatos>
    </cliente>  
    <cliente>
        <nome>Cliente2</nome>
        <contatos>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato3</nome>
            </contato>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato4</nome>
            </contato>
        </contatos>
    </cliente>
</clientes>
```

Preciso salvar no banco de dados em duas tabelas, o CLIENTE e seus CONTATOS, porém só consigo pegar cada TAG de uma vez e elas não tem referencia ficando assim:

```
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           ds.ReadXml(caminho);

           ds.Tables[0];
           //Aqui consigo obter os clientes
           ds.Tables[1];
           //Aqui consigo obter os contatos
```

Dessa forma não consigo criar as referências, as chaves no bando da relação CLIENTE x CONTATO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta é, a meu ver, a pior maneira de ler um XML. Use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) no lugar:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("clientes.xml");

var clientes = document.Root.Elements("cliente").ToList();
var primeiroCliente = clientes.First();
var contatosDoPrimeiroCliente = primeiroCliente.Elements("contatos").ToList();
var primeiroContato = contatosDoPrimeiroCliente.First();
var nomeDoPrimeiroContato = primeiroContato.Element("nome").Value;
```

XDocument implementa Linq em cima da leitura de um XML. Aí basta aplicar os métodos de extensão como nos exemplos pra obter os valores desejados.

Comment: Utilizando o Linq fui navegando nível por nível dos XElement depois de criar o XDocument utilizando um foreach simples